# Xcode Converting a string of equation to math equation

Tags: xcode, string, math, type-conversion, equation

I would like to ask how could I convert a string which inserted by user to a Math equation so xCode would understand.

For example if user enter this to a text field. "2*sin(2*M_PI*t)" which the "t" inside the equation is a variable inside the code and Xcode would able understand the equation like

double answer = 2*sin(2*M_PI*t);

Many Thanks
Kin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with just the standard cocoa classes, but the syntax gets somewhat ridiculous, and the amount of set-up is staggering too.

```
@interface MyExprTest : NSObject
-(void)run;
@end

@implementation MyExprTest

-(void)run {
    NSExpression *e = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)[NSPredicate
        predicateWithFormat:@"2*FUNCTION(2*PI*$t,'sin')==0"]
        leftExpression];
    NSMutableDictionary *vars = [NSMutableDictionary
                             dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.04], @"t",
                             nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", [e expressionValueWithObject:self context:vars]);
}

-(double)PI {
    return M_PI;
}

@end

@interface NSNumber (Trigonometry)
- (NSNumber*)sin;
@end

@implementation NSNumber (Trigonometry)

- (NSNumber*) sin {
    double result = sin([self doubleValue]);
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:result];
}

@end

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    MyExprTest *t = [[MyExprTest alloc] init];
    [t run];
    return 0;
}
```

A few pointers to note:

- The `t` in your expression became `$t` so that you could reference it from the `vars` dictionary
- The `M_PI` became simply `PI`; note the added method to support it
- There are no built-in trigonometric functions; see how `FUNCTION` and a category is used to get around it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm doing this for iOS, since the string in NSPredicate is @"2*FUNCTION(2*PI*$t,'sin')==0" that's mean when user enter a equation to the text field have to follow this format? Sorry I'm a beginner and never work around with NSExpression.

Comment: @Kin This should work in iOS. You will need to change the format of user's entry to match what `NSPredicate` expects. Note the `==0` at the end, it's a work-around for the lack of publicly available expression parsing API. Only the predicate parser is available, so you turn an expression `2*sin(2*M_PI*t)` into a predicate `2*sin(2*M_PI*t)==0`, and take its left part using `leftExpression` call.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use a math parser like [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser).

It allows variable substitution and has built-in constants.

Comment: Thanks! this math parser helps a lot!

Comment: whether DDMathParser is for both mac and ios application

Comment: @VigneshKumar Yes, iOS 4.0 or later and OS X 10.6 or later per his wiki page:  https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Adding-DDMathParser-to-your-project